# Show that |λ2| is the maximum of the ratios

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a symmetric real  $n$ x $n$ matrix with eigenvalues |λ1| >
|λ2| ≥ |λ3| ≥ · · · ≥ |λk| ≥ 0. Let W be the orthogonal complement of the
span of the λ1 eigenvectors. Show that |λ2| is the maximum of the ratios

$\frac{||Ax||}{||x|}$ where $x$ is  a non zero vector belonging to $W$ .

How do I do this? I do not know how to relate this with Spectral Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the spectral theorem, $A$ is diagonalizable with respect to an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. Then $W$ is the span of all the basis elements that are not $\lambda_1$-eigenvectors of $A$.

In particular, $A$ maps elements of $W$ to elements of $W$, so we can view $A$ as a linear map $W \to W$, whose largest absolute eigenvalue is $|\lambda_2|$.

---

More concretely, let $A=UDU^\top$ be the eigendecomposition of $A$.
Let $\tilde{U}$ be the result of throwing away the $\lambda_1$-eigenvectors,
and let $\tilde{D}$ be obtained by taking $D$ and throwing away the $\lambda_1$ entries (while shrinking the dimension to $\dim(W) \times \dim(W)$). Then for $x \in W$ we have $Ax=\tilde{U} \tilde{D} \tilde{U}^\top x$, so the maximum of $\|Ax\|/\|x\|$ over $x \in W$ is $|\lambda_2|$, the largest absolute eigenvalue of $\tilde{U} \tilde{D} \tilde{U}^\top$.